# How to get our own Wireless LAN Ip address using java

Tags: java

*Following code is giving Ethernet Address 
but I need to get Wirless LAN address*

```
InetAddress inet;
    try {
        inet = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        myIp.setText(inet.getHostAddress());
    } catch (UnknownHostException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(frontPageController.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
```

But what is the code to get wireless LAN ip address ??

Comment: Did you do any research? Did you study `java.net.NetworkInterface`?

Comment: Yes java.net.NetwokInterface class will give list of all IP addresses but I need only Wirless LAN Address @JimGarrison

Comment: Again, STUDY the `NetworkInterface` class.  There are more methods available.  You must be able to identify the interface you want given what the API returns (name, MAC, IP, etc). There is nothing in the API that explicitly discriminates a wireless interface from any other, because at this level they're all Ethernet.

Comment: There might be a 3rd party library that provides a lower-level API to the native WiFi layer but that would make your code non-portable.  Asking for help finding such a library is off-topic on StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example how you can explore your network interfaces with `java.net.NetworkInterface`:

```
@Test
    public void test() throws Exception {
        Enumeration<NetworkInterface> interfaces = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

        while (interfaces.hasMoreElements()) {
            NetworkInterface networkInterface = interfaces.nextElement();
            // drop inactive
            if (!networkInterface.isUp())
                continue;

            // smth we can explore
            Enumeration<InetAddress> addresses = networkInterface.getInetAddresses();
            while(addresses.hasMoreElements()) {
                InetAddress addr = addresses.nextElement();
                System.out.println(String.format("NetInterface: name [%s], ip [%s]",
                        networkInterface.getDisplayName(), addr.getHostAddress()));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code is for identifying IP of ethernet or wifi based on the type -

```
//useIPv4=true if you want to get ipv4 address
//type="eth0" if you want to get ethernet interface (eth0) IP : change with correct interface name
//type="wlan0" if you want to use wifi interface (wlan0)  : change with correct interface name
public static String getIPAddress(boolean useIPv4, String type) {
        try {
            List<NetworkInterface> interfaces = Collections.list(NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces());
            for (NetworkInterface intf : interfaces) {
                List<InetAddress> addrs = Collections.list(intf.getInetAddresses());
                for (InetAddress addr : addrs) {
                    if (!addr.isLoopbackAddress()) {
                        String sAddr = addr.getHostAddress();
                        boolean isIPv4 = sAddr.indexOf(':')<0;
                        if(intf.getDisplayName().equalsIgnoreCase(type)) { //checking here the interface type of your choice
                            if (useIPv4) {
                                if (isIPv4)
                                    return sAddr;
                            } else {
                                if (!isIPv4) {
                                    int delim = sAddr.indexOf('%'); // drop ip6 zone suffix
                                    return delim < 0 ? sAddr.toUpperCase() : sAddr.substring(0, delim).toUpperCase();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return "ERROR";
    }
```